# react native navigation Signup page

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am facing an issue in the Sign Up page of my application. When user sign up for the first time it should navigate to the edit profile page then to the home page. But when I try to navigate from edit to home, it's not navigating.
I am checking with a flag inside the home page whether the user is existing or not. if existing it will render the home page view, if not then it will render the Edit profile page. But in the edit profile page when I save the data, how to view the Home page?

````
   ```
main view
```      
            render()
                 {
                    return (
                        this.state.isExistingUser ?
                        <View>
                            <Text>Hellow World</Text>
                        </View> :   <View>
                            <TextInput placeholder=`full name` />
            <Button title=`SIGNUP` onPress={this.onClick} />
                        </View>
               )
                }
```
button click
```
    onClick() 
            {
                 const dbDetails = firestoreData.collection('users');
                 dbDetails.add({
                     'fname': 'Hi',
                    })
             }
````

Comment: Please add your implementation with a question.

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: Thankyou  I found the solution by setting state back inside the onCLick button